# Ember model access to belongsTo property return null

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I have a model Person with this property : `address_fk: DS.belongsTo('address')` refering to an Address model.

In the adress model, there are several properties such as zip_code , building ...

My goal is to create a computed property in Person to display the full address by accessing `this.get('address_fk.zip_code')` but it returns me *undefined*

I'm surely missing something here but I really don't know what.

Update : Problem solved, here is how :

```
adresse: computed('adresse_fk', function() {
return DS.PromiseObject.create({
  promise: this.get('adresse_fk').then((adresse) => {
    return adresse.get('escalier_etage_appartement') + ' ' + adresse.get('batiment') + ' ' + adresse.get('numero_nom_voie') + ' ' + adresse.get('code_postal') + ' ' + adresse.get('commune_fk.nom')
  })
});
```

}),

Comment: Are you sure the related record is fulfilled and server does has returned some content for it? Have in mind that a relationship maybe async and that the relationship is a PromiseObject.

Comment: I would need to see the definition for the relationship (on both the address and the person models) as well as the normalized payload that is given to the store. With that, I can help you easily :)

If you don't know where to see the normalized payload, in your serializer breakpoint or override `normalizeResponse` to log its return value.

Comment: Hi Jelhan, I updated my question below. Sometimes my value is showing up so I'm kind of confuse.

Comment: Hi Runspired, I added the two models down below. As for the serializer breakpoint i don't see what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are defining the computed property on the `Person` model. The computed property may return a PromiseObject for the address. You could try these two things -

1 Check for the presence of `adresse_fk`

```
// Person model
adresse: Ember.computed('adresse_fk', function() {
if this.get('adresse_fk'){
  return this.get('adresse_fk.escalier_etage_appartement') + ' ' 
   + this.get('adresse_fk.batiment') + ' ' + 
   this.get('adresse_fk.numero_nom_voie')
}
```

2 Use `then` to resolve promises

```
// Person model
adresse: Ember.computed('adresse_fk', function() {
this.get('adresse_fk').then( function(address){
  return address.get('escalier_etage_appartement') + ' ' 
   + address.get('batiment') + ' ' + 
   address.get('numero_nom_voie')
 }
}
```

I have not tested them but they should work.

Comment: Hi, indeed the promise idea was the right choice ! I used DS.PromiseObject.create

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
//Address
export default DS.Model.extend({
    point_de_consommation_fk: DS.hasMany('pointdeconsommation'),
    code_postal: DS.attr('string'),
    escalier_etage_appartement: DS.attr('string'),
    batiment: DS.attr('string'),
    numero_nom_voie: DS.attr('string'),
    commune_fk: DS.belongsTo('commune'),
    personne_set: DS.hasMany('personne')
})

// Person model
export default DS.Model.extend({
     categorie_code: DS.attr('personne-categorie-code'),
     email: DS.attr('string'),
     adresse_fk: DS.belongsTo('address'),
     telephone1: DS.attr('string'),
     telephone2: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: ''}),
     adresse: computed('adresse_fk', function() {
       return this.get('adresse_fk.escalier_etage_appartement') + ' ' 
       + this.get('adresse_fk.batiment') + ' ' + 
       this.get('adresse_fk.numero_nom_voie')
     }),
})
```

I also forgot to tell that sometimes my *undefined* value is showing 
   up. Maybe I need to wait on my template before calling the property?